# How to use .setBorder based on cell content?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm completely new to programming and I'm trying to write this ridiculous easy script but it just won't work.. Anyone who can help me out?

I think the script makes clear what I want to do but let met provide a short explanation: If cell1, cell2 and/or cell 3 is empty I want a red line to appear and if there's something within the cell I want a blue line to appear.

Right now the script only generates a blue line and then nothing.

```
function CreateBorder() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet =ss.getSheetByName("flyer");
  var cell1 = activeSheet.getRange("B12");
  var cell2 = activeSheet.getRange("B15");
  var cell3 = activeSheet.getRange("B18");

  if (cell1.getValue !== "") { 
    cell1.setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "blue", null);
  }
  else {

    cell1.setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "red", null);
  }


  if (cell2.getValue !== "") { 
    cell2.setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "blue", null);
  }
  else {
    cell2.setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "red", null);
  }


  if (cell3.getValue !== "") { 
    cell3.setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "blue", null);
  }
  else {
    cell3.setBorder(null, null, true, null, false, false, "red", null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getValue` is a function definition in the `range` object. It'll never be empty. Invoke your function by using `()` like `getValue()`.

```
Logger.log("getValue is a"+ cell1.getValue)
Logger.log("result of executing  function getValue is"+ cell1.getValue())
```

Answer (score 1):

`cell1.getValue` and the other similar expressions are using the incorrect syntax. The correct syntax is `cell1.getValue()`.

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue